# Simple batch render script is woking.. but without modifiers

Tags: python, modifiers

I have a blender script:

```
import bpy
# Get names of selected cameras
BR_Cameras = [obj.name for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects]
for x in BR_Cameras:
   # Setting Active Camera
   bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.context.scene.objects.get(x)
   # Activate Modifier in Render
   bpy.data.objects["Plane"].modifiers[x].show_render = True
   # Rename Output Path Node
   bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes["Output Node"].file_slots[0].path = x + "_"
   # Render Image (through compositor)
   bpy.ops.render.render()
   # Deactivate Modifier in Render
   bpy.data.objects["Plane"].modifiers[x].show_render = False
```

You can Render several cameras AND Activate/Deactivate Modifiers (on object named "Plane") with identical names to these Cameras.
[image]
But my script activate only first modifier for all Cameras: [image]

But i Need this result:

[image]

For some reason, blender is not updating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have unchecked "Persistend Data" or place this line of code to my script

```
bpy.context.scene.render.use_persistent_data = False
```

[image]

[Peristance Data in blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/render/cycles/render_settings/performance.html?highlight=persistent%20Data)

Actually i found out it by rendering my pictures manually, and I noticed that modifiers weren't updating when I activating/deactivating it **after first rendering**,
and at that moment I remembered Persistend Data function

Answer (score 2):

You can animate modifier visibility. Just press  <kbd>I</kbd>  while hovering over the camera or monitor icons of the modifier.

[image]

You can attach cameras to timeline markers pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>B</kbd>  with a camera selected and hovering mouse over the timeline to insert a marker and bind the camera to it on the current frame.

[image]

So you can set it up as an animation and just render it as animation. That might help you avoid scripting for this.